# women ancestors of Jesus

Tags: matthew

My question is: Why are four women of questionable backgrounds offered as ancestors of Jesus? (Maatthew 1: 1-17). Is there some significance in the fact that they aren't examples of "righteous" citizens?

Comment: Tamar and Ruth are considered as righteous. Why do you say four women of questionable background? Was Judah righteous? Was David more righteous than Bathsheba? Salvation entered the world through sinners, all.

Comment: There are several examples of non-righteousness in the lineage of Jesus. Perhaps it would help to define your question in terms of gender OR righteousness?